# Don't factor bundled master item into shipping

Tags: magento

If a bundled product is added to the cart, the item itself as well as each bundled option counts toward the number of items in the cart based on:

```
<?php $var = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() ?>
<?php echo count($var) ?>
```

It is looking like the best way to achieve accurate shipping rates (based on client's requirements) is going to simply be to reduce the number of items in the cart by 1 for each bundled product in the cart.

Is this going to be a messy fix? How would you implement this "feature"?

Comment: What is the products count if you use: Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

Comment: getAllVisibleItems() returns a count of 1 for each bundled item regardless of the number of options. Basically, it returns twice the value of getItemsCollection() (if each bundled item has a single option chosen).

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse no, you simply do custom shipping model, and implements your business rules to shipping. Take a look on this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module
It mighty be 'easy'